# How to plot a scatter plot with a radius given by a variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm pretty new to ggplot, I need to make a scatterplot with the size proportional to a variable of the df, so that some of the points get "zero radius" because a 0 value in the variable, but when I use the size aes, the points with 0 value are mapped to a non-zero radius point.

how can I get the desired effect?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please add an example or clarify. `ggplot(data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10, size = runif(10)), aes(x=x,y=y,size=size)) + geom_point()`

Comment: sorry, I'm doing this, ggplot(df, aes=(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point(aes=(size=variable)), where variable can take zero values, but this zero values aren't mapped to a zero radius point(I want this points to be absent from my plot), instead it seems that ggplot rescale the values so that zero values get non-zero size.

Comment: Hey Uziel, welcome to StackOverflow; to help others help you with your question please edit it to include that code you just commented here. :3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the help, "`scale_size_area` ensures that a value of 0 is mapped to a size of 0". [Also worth noting, you can get a similar effect if you use `scale_radius` or `scale_size` and set the lower limit of the `range` argument to zero]. So we can do:

```
df <- data.frame(x=0:5, y=0:5, s=0:5)

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size=s)) +
  scale_size_area()    # NB scale_size(range = c(0, 6)) also works
```

[image]

Note that this still shows the location of 'zero size' points using a single pixel.  If you want them to be actually invisible, you can filter out the rows of zero size like this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, size=s)) + 
  geom_point(data = df[df$s != 0,]) +
  scale_size_area()
```

Comment: This is misleading. The trivial solution `ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +   geom_point(aes(size=s))` already solves your problem. The addition of `scale_size_area` is not contributing to the solution in this case. It's just a helper function of size scaling (area scaling vs. radius scaling).

Comment: @shosaco - no you are wrong.  Omitting the `scale_size_area` produces a different plot, in which the smallest point has size = 1.  OP wants size=0 for the smallest point.

Comment: accepted. I gets obvious if you pass the resulting plot on to `ggplotly`, where points of size 0 have physical radius 0 (not so at the ggplot2 plot).